# How to upload files in JSF 1.1?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, tomahawk

I want to upload files in a JSF 1.1 project. JSF 1.1 doesn't support RichFaces file upload. I looked at Tomahawk, but I don't know how to use Tomahawk. Can anybody explain for me?

- Which JARs do I have to use?
- And taglibs?
- And `web.xml` configuration?
- And `faces-config.xml` configuration?

Or are there alternatives to Tomahawk?

Answer (score 4):

> *Which JARs do I have to use?*

The following ones:

- [tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/download.html)
- [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/download_fileupload.cgi)
- [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi)
- [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi)
- [commons-el](http://commons.apache.org/el/download_el.cgi)

I assume that you already have the JSF 1.1 JARs `jsf-api` and `jsf-impl`.

---

> *And taglibs?*

Just the Tomahawk one, next to the two usual core/html tags:

```xml
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="t" %>
```

---

> *And web.xml configuration?*

You need the `ExtensionsFilter`. This filter will take care that JSF gets the right parameters out of a `multipart/form-data` request body.

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

---

> *And faces-config.xml configuration?*

Nothing special. Just create a managed bean the usual way with a `UploadedFile` property which you bind to the `value` attribute of `<t:inputFileUpload>`.

#### See also:

- [How to upload files in JSF?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/02/uploading-files-with-jsf.html) (yes, it's targeted on JSF 1.2, but should work equally good in JSF 1.1).